# AngularJS: after-select-item not triggering

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

I am using angularjs version 1.6.4 with [angular-multiple-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-multiple-select)  module for multi selecting. Every thing is working fine. I am able to select from suggestions but whenever i do selection "after-select-item" directive is not triggering. According to angular-multiple-select module documentation

> afterSelectItem : Listen for event before adding an item

```
<div class="form-group float-label-control">
      <label>Skills</label>
      <multiple-autocomplete ng-model="model.user.skills"
                             object-property="name"
                             after-select-item="model.afterSelectItem"
                             suggestions-arr="model.skills">
      </multiple-autocomplete>
</div>
```

My controller few code lines:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var module = angular.module(__appName);
    function fetchSkills($http) {
    return $http.get(__apiRoot + "/skills")
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            })
}

function controller($http) {

    var model = this;

    model.$onInit = function () { 
        fetchSkills($http).then(function (skills) {
            model.skills = skills;
        });
    };

    model.afterSelectItem = function (item) {
        console.log("after select item");
        console.log(item);
    }
}

module.component("userEdit", {
    templateUrl: "components/user-edit/user-edit.template.html",
    bindings: {
        userId: "<",
        onUserSaved: "&"
    },
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["$http", controller]
});
```

}());